# onKeydown is not working when added dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to append some html in my web page using jQuery. My code is

```
 var s1 = "<div class='controls'><label class='inline labelspace'>Minimum Cart Value<input class='inline input-small' type='text' name='mincart' onKeydown=isNumberKey ></input></label>";
s1 += "<label class='inline labelspace'>Minimum No Of Items<input class='inline input-small' type='text' placeholder='Enter Integer' name='minitem' onKeydown=isNumberKey></input></label>" ;
s1 += "<label class='inline labelspace'>Location<input class='inline input-small' type='text' name='location' ></input></label>";
s1 += "<label class='inline labelspace'>Product Ids<input class='inline input-small' onKeydown=isValid type='text' name='products'></input></label></div>" ;
$("#lastrow").before(s1);
```

isNumberKey is a function whose source code is

```
function isNumberKey(evt) {
  console.log('coming to this');
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
    if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        return false;
    } else 
        return true;

}
```

Using these function, only numbers can be entered in the text box. When I assign some element like this
`$("#some_elem").onKeyDown(isNumberKey)` then it is working correctly but i want to know why its not working in first case.

Comment: There is no event named `onKeyDown` in jQuery. I think you are looking for `keydown` event.

Comment: If you want to see how this should work, check demo in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to `delegate` the event. Use :

```
$(document).on('keydown' , '.some-class', isNumberKey);
```

If you `append` new `elements` to your markup, the `event` wont be binded on them. So you need to delegate it.

Use a `class` instead of a `id`. Of course the `class` need to be added to the `appended` `div` or , in this case, to the `input` I guess.

If you use `$('.some-class').on('event', function(){})` the event will be attached only on **existing** elements that have `.some-class` . Using delegation will attacch the `event` on any `div` you want.

Comment: the difference between 
   `$("#some_elem").onKeyDown(isNumberKey)`
and
   `$(document).on('keydown' , '#some_elem', isNumberKey);`
is that the first one bind to an existing object and the second will handle every selected object even if it's created after the binding

Comment: tell how to accomplish it in HTML attribute

Comment: you have to run it into your script page, if you want, on dom ready.

Comment: @steo sorry, just wanted to clear on why it should work. that was before your edit

Answer (score -1):

Incase if you want to accompanish in HTML, try changing the code below

```
onKeydown="isNumberKey()"
```

Comment: Don't why I got minus.  His question **`$("#some_elem").onKeyDown(isNumberKey)` then it is working correctly but i want to know why its not working in first case**

Comment: `objElement.onkeydown = isNumberKey` I think this is right according to javascript syntax.

Comment: @Mr_Green But correcting the above line in his code will work right?

Comment: As per the question, @user1671639 seems to be right. wondering why negative voted